# What happened to Mr Saxon in the alternative universe in ‘Turn Left’?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode ‘Turn Left’, an alternative universe is created when Donna Noble turns right instead of left and gets a new job.

In this universe, the Doctor dies (without renegerating) whilst battling the Racnoss — i.e. prior to the events of series 3. We then see the events of the season 3 premiere (i.e. the Royal Hope Hospital being transported to the moon) and the subsequent Christmas special (the S.S. Titanic disaster) occur without the Doctor.

However, no mention is made of Mr Saxon becoming Prime Minister of the UK. In the original timeline, this was prompted by the Doctor precipitating the fall of Harriet Jones (in the Christmas special between series 1 and 2). I can’t see how the Doctor’s death during the encounter with the Racnoss would have prevented this.

So: where was Mr Saxon in the alternate timeline?

Comment: See here for [a better ‘Turn Left’ question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60620/in-alternate-timeline-why-didnt-titanic-crash-destroy-life-from-earth).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no reason to think that he ever stopped being Professor Yana at the end of the universe, and most likely died with all of the remaining humans when he was unable to get his rocket to work.

Remember, Yana was The Master hidden behind a Chameleon Arch, and had forgotten everything about it. It's only when the Tenth Doctor arrives and Martha recognizes the fob watch that Yana even thinks to open it, and only when Ten lends his assistance that he's able to get the escape ship working, and only when The Master steals Ten's TARDIS and The Doctor locks the TARDIS to a specific year that The Master even comes up with the plan to become Prime Minister. Without The Doctor, there never would have been a Harold Saxon.

Note that we don't actually know what happens to a Time Lord who dies while in "human form" due to a Chameleon Arch. They may simply die, or they may regenerate and regain their memories in the process. Even in the latter case, without The Doctor and his TARDIS readily available, we still have no reason to expect The Master to go to 21st century Earth and become Harold Saxon as revenge.

Comment: Oh! Yes of course, I’d forgotten that’s how he gets to Earth in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Since The Doctor died before going with Martha to the end of the universe, the Master has no way of getting his hands in the Tardis, does not recover his memory, and does not go to the UK.