# Why didn't the Titanic crash destroy all life on Earth?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Voyage of the Damned* episode of *Doctor Who (2005)*, the Nuclear Storm Drive of the Titanic was capable of destroying all life on the planet.

From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-0.htm):

> **The Doctor:** Oh, yes. If we hit the planet, the Nuclear Storm explodes and wipes out life on Earth. Midshipman, I need you to fire up the engine containment field and feed it back into the core.

Conversation with Capricorn:

> **Capricorn:** I have men waiting to retrieve me from the ruins and enough off-world accounts to retire me to the beaches of Penhaxico Two, where the ladies, so I'm told, are very fond of metal.
>   **The Doctor:** So that's the plan. A retirement plan. Two thousand people on this ship, six billion underneath us, all of them slaughtered, and why? Because Max Capricorn is a loser.

---

In a later episode *Turn Left*, Donna was pushed into an alternate timeline by a fortune teller in which she never met The Doctor. Due to this, The Doctor died. Without him, the Titanic crashed into Buckingham Palace, which destroyed London. Why did it destroy London only?

Is this a known plot hole? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Speculation only, but since we do hear from Rose that the Torchwood group steps in during another one of the disasters that the Doctor prevented, it's not inconceivable to think that something like UNIT, or Sarah Jane Smith, or some other former companion still on Earth might have been able to do something to lessen the impact, partially shut down the drive, or otherwise mitigate the effect of the crash.

Comment: @Roger All were dead by now except Cap. Jack Harness (who was also not on Earth).

Comment: There's some fan speculation at http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Theory:Doctor_Who_television_discontinuity_and_plot_holes/Turn_Left that "The Trickster", who was in the Sarah Jane Adventures Episode *Whatever Happened To Sarah Jane?*, may have stopped world-destroying events in the *Turn Left* universe, since in the alternate Sarah-Jane-less universe he created in WHTSJ, he stopped other invasions that SJ should have foiled (because he "feeds on chaos", and wanted to keep SJ from stopping world destruction by a meteor, which would be more random than destruction for "profit, power, revenge").

Comment: A hole in that theory is that *Whatever Happened to Sarah Jane?* actually aired in October 2007 before *Turn Left* in June 2008, I'm not sure if there were any references to the years on either show that would pin down the fact that the meteor was scheduled to hit before *Turn Left* though.

Comment: Also, *Voyage of the Damned* was December 2007 so maybe the exact dates are ambiguous enough that you could imagine the Titanic Crash happened slightly before the meteor, so The Trickster stopped it in the alternate universe of *Turn Left*, but in the *Turn Left* universe Sarah Jane was still around and stopped the meteor in pretty much the same way.

Comment: Another fan speculation at http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=867312 is that some characters on the Titanic like Astrid or Frame may still have been able to shut down the nuclear storm drive before impact, but without the Doctor's help couldn't prevent the crash itself.

Comment: It is all very timey wimey

Comment: Captain Jack and Torchwood weren't dead/taken to Sontar until after the crash. That happened in the alternate universe's version of "The Sontaran Stratagem", which came after the Titanic crash. They could have interfered somehow, and I don't think it was ever said that UNIT was put out of action. As for the meteor thing, I don't see the issue. The Trickster could just stop the meteor, and he would if it meant more chaos on Earth. It wouldn't really matter if the meteor was due to hit before or after the crash.

Comment: @Amy Make an answer with these. I did forget that Sontaran crisis happened after Titanic crash.

Comment: @Amy - the idea is that the Trickster *wanted* the meteor to crash because that would be a chaotic or random way for humanity to die off, so he had to prevent earlier disasters where humanity would have been destroyed by aliens with more discernable motives. From the transcript at http://www.chakoteya.net/SJA/108.htm : "Those other species, they invade for profit, power, revenge. The meteor is pure chaos. The destruction of the Earth for no reason at all, just blind chance. This is food for me."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Titanic was in the process of pulling up in the alternate universe. Since the Doctor states that with the drive turned off, the anti-gravity drives won't work...

> *"As soon as it stops, the Titanic falls"*

...we can assume that *someone* on the ship (possibly Astrid, Midshipman Frame or even the 5th Doctor (Due to the events of the Time-Crash mini-episode) {h/t to @Amy for that suggestion} could have made some efforts to control the ship and restart the Storm Drive or reactivate the engine's containment field.

The Doctor also makes reference to a "*Secondary Storm Drive*" being activated by the heat of re-entry. We can presume that this also happened in the alternate universe and while it may have been insufficient to allow the ship to miss the ground it would have probably provided some level of containment to the engines.

Comment: How could Astrid or Midshipman even survive without The Doctor? The Doctor alerted them, saved them from vacuum opening and from those robots.

Comment: @sachinShekhar - The Doctor interacted with both characters. His absence would have affected their movements.

Comment: Affected their movements positively or negatively?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I don't think there's any way of telling.

Comment: It's thing of common sense that they were just like other crew members without The Doctor.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: really? Characters in the Doctor Who universe do do stuff without the Doctor there. We just don’t usually see it, because we’re watching the Doctor.

Comment: This is purely speculation here, but maybe the Fifth Doctor tried to help but was forced to abandon it for some reason. His and Ten's TARDISes crashed into each other just prior to the Titanic impacted Ten's, so if Ten's TARDIS wasn't there, then presumably, Five's would have been hit and he would have been the one to go through those events.

Comment: @Amy Wow, that's great speculation. Turn that into answer.

Comment: Thanks, and I would, but I don't really have any in-show facts to back it up, and unsubstantiated answers are generally to be avoided. Nothing wrong with headcanon-ing it, though.

Comment: @Amy - That's a brilliant deduction. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: That's a bit harsh...

Comment: @EvilAngel Alonso was actually the safest person on the ship behind Max, he was the one who actually warned the Doctor about the Host killing everyone and he locked himself in the bridge away from them by himself.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a plot hole. In "Turn Left," had the Titanic done what was shown in Voyage of the Damned that would have happened had The Doctor not have pulled it up then the world would be destroyed since you turned right there would be no wait to come back. It was necessary to only blow up London to advance the plot of "Turn Left". Also the directors and producers probably do not think that anyone pays attention to such a detail from a long time ago. And they might not even remember that detail themselves.